# concatenation until empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a code to concatenate 3 columns namely YR which corresponds to cell A2, JJ which corresponds to cell B2 and YA which corresponds to cell D2. when i clicked a button i want it display the answer to G2. here's my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim YR As String
Dim JJ As String
Dim YA As String
Dim RF As String

YR = Range("A2")
JJ = Range("B2")
YA = Range("D2")
RF = YR & "." & JJ & "." & YA
Range("G2") = RF

End Sub
```

my problem now is how can i made this code to work until there's a blank cell?? i've search a code regarding this which is:

```
Range("A1").Select 
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) 
‘codes here
ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select 
Loop
```

how can i made my code and thanks in advanced!

Comment: You want to contatenate cells A2->n2 where n2 is the last non-empty cell in that row?

Comment: Sorry, your initial code works and you're now trying to make it do the same thing on every row after until a blank row is encountered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code if you don't wanna loop.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G2:G" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6] & ""."" & RC[-5] & ""."" & RC[-3]"

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question, the following code might help (I've not tested it though)

```
Sub catrow(row as integer)
Dim YR As String
Dim JJ As String
Dim YA As String
Dim RF As String

YR = Range("A" & row).value2
JJ = Range("B" & row).value2
YA = Range("D" & row).value2
RF = YR & "." & JJ & "." & YA
Range("G" & row) = RF
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Target As Range
Dim Row As Integer
Row = 1
Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Row)
Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Value)
    catrow(row)
    Set Target = Target.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help! yup you understood my question. there's nothing wrong with your code but it's not working when i clicked the button?